# javascript busting running sound

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

morning all, trying to run a sound effect in canvas, while displaying all attributes on canvas. Trying to fire all with Javascript. (sorry, this is the best explanation I could use to describe) either way, I literally copied the script from a book, and manipulated path to wav and ogg files. I get a blank screen when I run, which is different than what I am seeing in the book. I can get the sound to play, but no display of the yellow box with attributes.
Also, something else driving me nuts... When I run my script externally, in the drawfunction(), when I try to stroke the rectangle, I get an issue with the code burping when trying 
             context.strokeRect(5, 5, theCanvas.width−10, theCanvas.height−10);

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CH7EX4: Playing A Sound With No Tag</title>
<script src="modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);

var audioElement;
function eventWindowLoaded() 
{
    audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    document.body.appendChild(audioElement);
    var audioType = supportedAudioFormat(audioElement);
    if (audioType == "") 
    {
        alert("no audio support");
        return;
    }

    audioElement.setAttribute("src", "audio/shot." + audioType);
    audioElement.addEventListener("canplaythrough",audioLoaded,false);
}

function supportedAudioFormat(audio) 
{
    var returnExtension = "";
    if (audio.canPlayType("audio/ogg") =="probably" ||
    audio.canPlayType("audio/ogg") == "maybe") 
    {
        returnExtension = "ogg";
    } 

    else if(audio.canPlayType("audio/wav") =="probably" ||
    audio.canPlayType("audio/wav") == "maybe") 
    {
        returnExtension = "wav";
    } 

    /*else if(audio.canPlayType("audio/mp3") == "probably" ||
    audio.canPlayType("audio/mp3") == "maybe") 
    {
        returnExtension = "mp3";
    }*/

    return returnExtension;
}

function canvasSupport () 
{
    return Modernizr.canvas;
}

function audioLoaded(event) 
{
    canvasApp();
}

function canvasApp() 
{
    if (!canvasSupport()) 
    {
        return;
    }

    function drawScreen () 
    {
        //Background
        context.fillStyle = '#ffffaa';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);

        //Box
        //context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        //context.strokeRect(5, 5, theCanvas.width−10, theCanvas.height−10);

        // Text
        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.fillText ("Duration:" + audioElement.duration, 20 ,20);
        context.fillText ("Current time:" + audioElement.currentTime, 20 ,40);
        context.fillText ("Loop: " + audioElement.loop, 20 ,60);
        context.fillText ("Autoplay: " +audioElement.autoplay, 20 ,80);
        context.fillText ("Muted: " + audioElement.muted, 20 ,100);
        context.fillText ("Controls: " + audioElement.controls, 20 ,120);
        context.fillText ("Volume: " + audioElement.volume, 20 ,140);
        context.fillText ("Paused: " + audioElement.paused, 20 ,160);
        context.fillText ("Ended: " + audioElement.ended, 20 ,180);
        context.fillText ("Source: " + audioElement.currentSrc, 20 ,200);
        context.fillText ("Can Play OGG: " + audioElement.canPlayType("audio/ogg"),
        20 ,220);
        context.fillText ("Can Play WAV: " + audioElement.canPlayType("audio/wav"),
        20 ,240);

    }

var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
var audioElement = document.getElementById("theAudio");
audioElement.play();
setInterval(drawScreen, 33);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
<canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="300">
Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>

<div id="loadingStatus">
0%
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 600px; ">
<audio id="theAudio" controls >
<source src="audio/shot.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="audio/shot.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's a code burp? Are we talking audible sound here or error? If it's an error then let us know what it is.

Comment: sometimes I take the code into dreamweaver for code hinting, and it shows me that line as having an error. I can swap the minuses out with dashes and the error goes away (somehow). sorry, I edited the code a touch, the code available now is the code I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Just to eliminate the obvious... are you sure you have "modernizr-1.6.min.js" in the same directory as the HTML file above? And the audio files exist in a subdirectory ("audio") in the same folder?

Comment: yep, moderizer there. I can get the controls and actually play the sound, just can't get my yellow box to pop on in canvas on screen to view all attributes.

Comment: sorry, mistyped, (modernizer) is there

Comment: figured it out, somehow... commented out my error line (the contextRect line) still not sure why that line is erroring out?...